# How do I code the optical flow calculations for the left half and the right half of the image?

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I want to calculate optical flow on the left half and the right half of the captured video seperately. Using the results from the left and right half I want to eventually detect if the user(i.e. the camera) is moving forward or backward.

Currently, I have this system going for the left half of the screen. The code looks like this:

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static void help()
{
    cout << "*** Using OpenCV version " << CV_VERSION <<" ***"<< endl;
    cout << "\n\nUsage: \n"
            "\tESC - quit the program\n"
            "\tr - auto-initialize tracking\n"
            "\tc - delete all the points\n"
            "\tn - switch the \"night\" mode on/off\n"<< endl;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    help();
     //Termination of the algo after 20 iterations or accuracy going under 0.03 
    TermCriteria termcrit(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, 0.3);
    Size subPixWinSize(10,10), winSize(31,31);
    const int MAX_COUNT = 500;
    bool needToInit = false;
    bool nightMode = false;
    //Video capture is from the default device i.e. the webcam
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if( !cap.isOpened() )
    {
        cout << "Could not initialize capturing...\n";
        return 0;
    }

    namedWindow( "Half screen Optical flow Demo!", 1 );
    Mat gray, prevGray, image;
    vector<Point2f> points[2];

    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;

        //Output from the Videocapture is piped to 'frame'
        cap >> frame;
        if( frame.empty() )
            break;

        frame.copyTo(image);
        cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // Night mode not disabled
        if( nightMode )
            image = Scalar::all(0);


        //This line saves into 'gray' only the left half of the original image. Thus making the detection of optical only on the left side possible.
        gray = gray(Range(1,480), Range(1,320));



        if( needToInit || points[0].size()<=5)
        {                  
            goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, points[1], MAX_COUNT, 0.01, 10, Mat(), 3, 0, 0.4);
            cornerSubPix(gray, points[1], subPixWinSize, Size(-1,-1), termcrit);

        }
        else if( !points[0].empty() )
        {
            vector<uchar> status;
            vector<float> err;
            if(prevGray.empty())
                gray.copyTo(prevGray);
            calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGray, gray, points[0], points[1], status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);
            size_t i, k;

            for( i = k = 0; i < points[1].size(); i++ )
            {
                if( !status[i] )
                    continue;

                points[1][k++] = points[1][i];  
                circle(image, points[1][i], 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8);
            }
            points[1].resize(k);
        }      
        needToInit = false;
        imshow("Half screen Optical flow Demo!", image);

        char c = (char)waitKey(10);
        if( c == 27 )
            break;
        switch( c )
        {
        case 'r':
            needToInit = true;
            break;
        case 'c':
            points[0].clear();
            points[1].clear();
            break;
        case 'n':
            nightMode = !nightMode;
            break;
        }
        std::swap(points[1], points[0]);
        cv::swap(prevGray, gray);
    }
    cap.release();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I do this for the right half of the screen as well?

If I simply replicate the functions from above, say by modifying the image=image(Range(), Range()) values etc. I am not getting any output.

EDIT: Should I write out the part where the optical flow is calculated to a separate function and call it twice - once for the left half of the image and then for the right half?

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve, i.e. what you mean by moving "forward or backward" (towards the camera/away from the camera or left->right/right->left?) and how you are planning to detect this by using the optical flow?

Comment: @flix -  
What I am trying to implement succinctly is [visual odometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_odometry)

Using optical flow, if majority of the corners detected on the left half move to the left **and** those on the right half move to the right, I will conclude that the camera is moving towards the subject - and vice versa. (_So in a sense, towards and away from the camera and not left->right_)